Install g++ 11 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed
I am trying to install g++ 11 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.
By default via Zypper, g++ 13 is installed, but I need g++ 11 for my project.
This is what I am following :
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:gcc/openSUSE_Factory/devel:gcc.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install gcc11

This is resulting in the following error :
Retrieving repository 'devel:gcc' metadata ..........................................................................................................[error]
Repository 'devel:gcc' is invalid.
[devel:gcc|https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
History:
- [|] Error trying to read from 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/'

Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Skipping repository 'devel:gcc' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'gcc11' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'gcc11' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.

Please provide some steps to fix this issue

The name of the repository has changed, see https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/

You can use:
zypper in gcc11-c++
